# How do I split Hyper terminal into two panes?

Tags: terminal, hyperterminal

I'm using Vercel's [Hyper](https://github.com/vercel/hyper) terminal and want to split into two panes. How do I do this?

I searched for a while and couldn't find a good answer despite reading the documentation. There appear to be plugins, but can I do this without a special plugin?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it in Windows:

1. Click on the top left the 3 horizontal lines for the menu to appear.
2. Click File -> Split Right (or Split Down)

Or

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) on Windows.

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) on Mac.