# How do I open a second window of Hyper terminal?

Tags: terminal, hyperterminal

I would like to open a second window of Vercel's Hyper terminal. How do I do this?

On Mac, I tried pulling a tab out, but tabs can't be reordered. I also tried opening a new instance of the terminal, but that didn't work either. Even typing `hyper` in the hyper terminal itself doesn't work, or `open -a hyper`.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [How do I split Hyper terminal into two panes?](https://superuser.com/questions/1721997/how-do-i-split-hyper-terminal-into-two-panes) Why not just edit the extra information into your original question, rather than open up a new one?

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate. There's a difference between having a window split in two panes, still being one window, and having two windows, like two instances of Chrome.

Comment: What happens when/if you press Cmd+Shift+N?